# How do I constrict regex matches to exact substrings with the exception of certain characters as long as they are followed by a space or new line?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say we have the string:

> The rocket is going to Mars. Yes, the rocket.\n Follow us at rocket.mars.com for info about our rockets.\n P.S. We live for this rocket, all hail the glorious rocket.

I want to match the substring `rocket`. But, only match the bolded:

> The **rocket** is going to Mars. Yes, the **rocket**.\n Follow us at rocket.mars.com for info about our rockets. \n P.S. We live for this **rocket**, all hail the glorious **rocket**.

The closest I got to writing the regex required to do this is (hint -- it does not work):

`(?:^|)rocket(?:$|)`

The regex should constrain the matches to ones where:

- The matched substring is not a substring of a larger word

  - `rockets` is therefore not matched
- The substring can be followed by a *space*. It can also be followed by a *period* or a *comma* but **only if** what follows is either a *whitespace* () or a *new line character* (`\n`)

  - We don't match the *rocket* in *rocket.mars.com* because it doesn't meet the second part of the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe you might want to design some expression similar to,

```
(?i)\brocket\b(?!\.[a-z0-9])
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/g2IvGW/1/)

and we can exclude anything else that'd be undesired after `rocket` using alternation, with some similar expression:

```
(?i)\brocket\b(?!\.[a-z0-9]|[#-])
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/QSmN5a/1/)

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WeXXyK/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/WeXXyK/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(?i)\brocket\b(?!\.[a-z0-9]|[#-])"
test_str = "The rocket, is going to Mars. Yes, the rocket.\\n Follow us at rocket.mars.com for info about our rockets. \\n P.S. We live for this rocket,all hail the glorious rocket. rocket;rocket,rocket:rocket.1:rocket.c #rocket# rocket-science"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
\brocket(?=[.,]?\s)
```

It's also very fast (efficient) in searching for words.

Answer (score 0):

You might match rocket preceded by a word boundary. Use a positive lookahead to assert what is in the right is either a space or a dot/comma followed by () or a whitespace char.

```
\brocket(?= |[.,](?=[()\s]))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/akd4lq/1)

Answer (score -1):

You were almost there with your regex.

You can make sure that if fits your conditions by checking that what follows is either a space, a dot/comma followed by a newline/space, or a dot with it being the end of the string with the following regex:

```
(?:^|)rocket(?= |[.,][\n ]|.$)
```

Comment: This is a skimpy answer that's no better than one of the question's comments. A more concrete explanation of why this is the correct answer would make a lot of difference.

Comment: @DavidM I added some details